# CFSG-free bound for the number of generators of a finite simple group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, cfsg-free

We know that every finite simple group can be generated by $2$ elements.

This (correct me if I'm wrong) was proved, as far as I know, by Steinberg (Steinberg, R. (1962). Generators for Simple Groups. Canadian Journal of Mathematics, 14, 277-283) for Chevalley groups and by Aschbacher and Guralnick (M. Aschbacher, R. Guralnick, Some applications of the first cohomology group, Journal of Algebra, Volume 90, Issue 2, 1984, Pages 446-460, Theorem B) for the other simple groups, using the classification of the finite simple groups (CFSG).

We also know, by an easy application of Lagrange's theorem, that a group of order $n$ can be generated by at most $\log_2(n)$ elements.

My question is the following. Are there results proving that every simple group of finite order $n$ can be generated by $d$ elements, where $d$ is some quantity between $2$ and $\log_2(n)$ (for example $\log_2 \log_2 (n)$ or - more optimistically - an unspecified constant) without using the classification of finite simple groups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Still elementary, but marginally stronger than the $\log_{2}(n)$ bound is: every non-Abelian finite simple group $G$ of order $n$ can be generated by fewer than $\log_{p}(n)$ elements, where $p$ is the largest prime divisor of $\lvert G\rvert$. In particular (using Burnside's $p^{a}q^{b}$-theorem), such a group $G$ can be generated by fewer than $\log_{5}(n)$ elements, since we always have $p \geq 5$. This improves the $\log_{2}(n)$ bound by a  factor of at least $2$, but is still very weak. The proof is easy and elementary— $G$ is generated by its elements of order $p$. Let $S$ be a set of elements of order $p$ of $G$ which generates $G$ with $\lvert S\rvert$ minimal. Then for each positive integer $j$, any $j$ elements of $S$
generate a subgroup of order $p^{j}$ or greater, so $\lvert S\rvert < \log_{p}(\lvert G\rvert)$.

I don't know what the best known "elementary" bound is (or even if this is a well-defined quantity). I seriously doubt whether there is a constant-type bound known without using CFSG.

Comment: I would be very surprised if you do better that $|S| < C \log(|G|)$ for some constant $C$ without CFSG.